# Hook and send Woocommerce data after click Place Order button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, buttons

I'm finding the way to add a hook to my woo commerce check out page (http://localhost/checkout)  I'm tend to send cart items and billing address, user information to another page such as http://localhost/hooking after clicking Place Order button for more further purpose, is it possible, and how to do it?

Comment: The best would be to do it on order completed

Comment: Cus I have another payment method, which need Woocommerce cart items to start paying. @@. Very confusing stuff @@.

Thank for responding, @Mederic.

Answer (score 3):

For this three possibilities:

If you really want to do it on order place you would have to use the hook:

[woocommerce_new_order](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/)

However I would recommend you use the hook:

[woocommerce_order_status_completed](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_order_status_completed/)

This would make sure that the order is finished when you send then information.

To catch the information before billing you could always use:

[woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form)

If this still isn't working you could check the hook list:

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

You then would simply have something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'wc_send_order_to_mypage' );
function wc_send_order_to_mypage( $order_id ) {
$shipping_add = [
            "firstname" => $order->shipping_first_name,
            "lastname" => $order->shipping_last_name,
            "address1" => $order->shipping_address_1,
            "address2" => $order->shipping_address_2,
            "city" => $order->shipping_city,
            "zipcode" => $order->shipping_postcode,
            "phone" => $order->shipping_phone,
            "state_name" => $order->shipping_state,
            "country" => $order->shipping_country
        ];
//from $order you can get all the item information etc 
//above is just a simple example how it works
//your code to send data
}
```

---

Since the ultimate goal is to have your own payment system I would recommend you check out this tutorial that explains how to integrate your own payment gateway

https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/

Comment: How about using this hook: woocommerce_review_order_after_submit . The problem is, my http://localhost/hooking is a php page, I've tried putting some code like `global $woocommerce;
        $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
        function process_payment($order_id) {
            $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
            return array('result' => 'success', 'redirect' => $order->get_checkout_payment_url( true ));
        }`
but it seem doesn't work

Comment: The code I gave you should be in a plugin or in the functions.php of your theme and in that function `wc_send_order_to_mypage` you make a post request to your php page for instance

Comment: Thank you, but how can I get the item list and bring it to `mypage` ?

Comment: If you dont know how to make a redirection in php you shouldn't be coding something like this. check this: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-create-a-simple-woocommerce-payment-gateway/

Comment: Yahh, iI'll check that out, thank for you help, mate. Thank a lot !!!!.