# How to get the checkout form data from checkout page when place-order button is clicked

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to get the `form-fields` on `checkout` page when the user clicks on `place-order` button.

For this I tried different `hooks`, but the control does not even enter into mine block of code

I'm using the following.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_process_order');
function custom_process_order(){

   //do some your magic here
   print_r( WC()->checkout()->get_posted_data() );
   exit();
}
```

With this code, I got nothing.

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34674663/adding-a-hook-to-place-order-button-in-woocommerce) and [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291766/hook-and-send-woocommerce-data-after-click-place-order-button), but no success.

How can I get all the `form fields` when `place-order` buttons is clicked.

**Note:**

I don't want to get them via `js` or `JQuery` to get the fields data, I want to use proper `hook` for this.

Answer (score 0):

The place-order form button is actually called woocommerce_checkout_place_order, and the code in WC_Form_Handler passes this on to WC_Checkout process_checkout().

Here's [the relevant code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.1.1/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L1083). You probably want to hook:

- woocommerce_before_checkout_process or woocommerce_checkout_process, which happen before this code reads the items from posted data itself (although you could call WC()->checkout()->get_posted_data() yourself I think)
- woocommerce_after_checkout_validation, which is passed the posted data as its first argument along with an errors array
- woocommerce_checkout_order_processed if you want the data after the checkout is complete.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
I want to know which hook should I use, so that when I click on `place-order` button, I want to get the data that is in its `$_POST`, as I'm beginner I don't have much idea

Comment: Any of these should work. The two in the first bullet will only have the data in $_POST and the other two will have a parsed copy of the data passed as an argument to the hook handler.

Comment: I used `woocommerce_checkout_process`, and attached my `function` to it, where I just have only one line of code i.e `print_r($_POST)` , but it does not do anything, it again redirects me to the `order received page`, which is kind of thank you page.
My `$_POST`  is not getting anything ?

Comment: OK, I'm not sure then. Maybe try `print_r( WC()->checkout()->get_posted_data() );` Is your page submitting the checkout via AJAX? However it should end up in the same code as a POST I think.

Comment: No, the page is not submitting through AJAX, the page is refreshed and redirects me to the kind of thank you page.
But when I use `exit()` in my function just to know that either my function is being called or not I got this `SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0`

Comment: can you please write a block of `code` that could possibly get the `posted data` when the place order is clicked ?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code you suggested, please have a look, it should work or not ?